# Debug small code - receiving error

Tags: post, curl, couchdb

I am receiving the error when running the code:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$  curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/books/_temp_view?group=true -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
```

> "map": "function(doc) {
>      if (doc.formats) {
>      for (var i in doc.formats) {
>      emit(doc.formats[i]);
>      }
>      }
>      }",
>      "reduce": "_count"
>      }'
>   **{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}** 
>   ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably having problems with spacing or quotes in the shell. Try saving your JSON in a file, then pass that file name to curl instead of writing the JSON on the command line.

Example assuming your JSON lives in /tmp/ex.json:

```
curl -XPOST -Hcontent-type:application/json -d@/tmp/ex.json http://localhost:5984/books/_temp_view?group=true
```